# Unfinished hook action(s) on exit: (vite:build-import-analysis) transform "/virtual:/@storybook/builder-vite/vite-app.js"

Tags: reactjs, vite, storybook

I recently installed storybook and I am trying to use it in my project. When I run it, it works fine. However, when I build it using build-storybook, I get this error:

```
./sb-common-assets/fonts.css doesn't exist at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
transforming (6) src/stories/Button.stories.tsUnexpected early exit. This happens when Promises returned by plugins cannot resolve. Unfinished hook action(s) on exit:
(vite:build-import-analysis) transform "/virtual:/@storybook/builder-vite/vite-app.js"
(commonjs--resolver) resolveId "@storybook/react/dist/entry-preview.mjs" 
=> Failed to build the preview
Error: Unexpected early exit. This happens when Promises returned by plugins cannot resolve. Unfinished hook action(s) on exit:
(vite:build-import-analysis) transform "/virtual:/@storybook/builder-vite/vite-app.js"
(commonjs--resolver) resolveId "@storybook/react/dist/entry-preview.mjs"
```

For context, this is my `.storybook/main.ts` file:

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";

import { join, dirname } from "path";

/**
 * This function is used to resolve the absolute path of a package.
 * It is needed in projects that use Yarn PnP or are set up within a monorepo.
 */
function getAbsolutePath(value: string): any {
  return dirname(require.resolve(join(value, "package.json")));
}
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-links"),
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-essentials"),
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-onboarding"),
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-interactions"),
  ],
  framework: {
    name: getAbsolutePath("@storybook/react-vite"),
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  async viteFinal(config, { configType }) {
    //Remove vite-plugin-eslint errors as it cause an ESLint config file not found error in /virtual:/@storybook/builder-vite.
   const filteredPlugins = config.plugins.filter(plugin => plugin.name !== 'vite-plugin-eslint');
   return {
     ...config,
     plugins: filteredPlugins,
   };
 },
};

export default config;
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I had the same problem in a Yarn 4 PnP + React Typescript + Vite + Storybook configuration running in a Docker container and I could solve this issue by reinitializing Storybook running `yarn dlx storybook@latest init`.